# How do I connect GPS receiver module with USB interface?

Tags: gps, interface, usb-device

I have a GPS module [DS-330R](http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/info_GPS_330R.html) which has 6 connections, two are not used, one is Ground, one is Vcc (3.8 to 12.0V DC) and the remaining two are Data+ and Data- for USB connection. My questions are:

- Can I simply connect Vcc to a separate supply such as a wall wart, say 5V, and the two Data to a USB connector, and in that case do I have to connect Ground also?
- Could I use instead the 5V available on the USB port of my computer for Vcc and Ground?
- Do I have to take any precautions that I have not anticipated?

Comment: It is unlikely that the module is intended to be connected to a PC's USB port; more likely you should be using it with a USB host connection of another chip, much like the Ethernet chip is connected on the RPi.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams A USB host port is a USB host connection, embedded or connectorized.  Ground should be connected, power can come from elsewhere or the port if requirements are in spec.

Comment: I connected the GPS receiver module directly to a USB port on my pc, for power supply and data, and it is now, after a long (at least 1 1/2 hours) warm up period, it is sending a stream of data to a processing language program that  displays it. Thanks all for the comments and answer, all now happily resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the specs of the USB port. If it can handle the current draw, it should be OK. Otherwise, use a USB powered hub or external +5V. Grounds should be connected.

You need protection on the GPS module side when the external protection kicks in at a much higher current level. Again check when the P.C USB port or the USB hub or the exteranl source limit the current draw.

Comment: Thank you nvd, I would accept that as answered if you could please explain more fully what you mean by "You need protection on the GPS module side ...". I am going to use a laptop for my first tests. The GPS module draws less than 45mA, and there will, at least for a start, not be anything else connected to the laptop's USB ports, except a wireless mouse. (I can't abide those touch sensitive pads.)

Comment: If I were you, I would connect it directly.

If you are careful, read on:

The minimum voltage the module accepts is 3.8V. Let's take the laptop's voltage as 5V (it may be a bit less though; 4.8V).

Add a resistor in series = (5V - 3.8V) / 45mA = 26.6 ohm.

Go for a 20 ohm resistor and the module will not be able to draw too much if things go wrong.

Generally resettable poly-fuses or protection ICs are used but you do not need to go that fancy.

I feel there is some protection inside the module but cannot find that in the datasheet.

Comment: Moreover, 45mA may be the average current. There may be a peak current of more than that. In such a case, voltage will drop below 3.8V and may reset the module. If that happens, put a capacitor between VCC and GND after the resistor, towards the module side.